Has anyone ever tried seeing Shedim via the gemara's techniques?
Ever since first learning about the techniques described in the gemara for seeing Shedim's footprints and seeing the Shedim themselves (Berachot 6a) when I was in seventh grade, I've sometimes wondered what it would be like to try out one of these experiments (but for many different reasons don't actually plan on ever following through myself). The gemara there mentions that Rabbi Bevai bar Abayei tried the second one out and lost his mind, until the other sages prayed for him to be healed. I was wondering whether there are later sources that describe other people having tried out these particular techniques.

Sounds like a good idea for a youtube video

“Kids, don’t try this at home”

@CuriousYid yes, well-put.

I don't think any genuine talmid chacham will try this out as the gemara itself warns not to doit
